# Filter IO [Maybe String] to IO [String]

Tags: haskell, monads

How to filter `IO [Maybe String]` to only keep the `Just` values of the list using `>>=` and keep the IO context.

```
-- returns Just, if the passed binary-name is not present on the system
binDoesntExist :: String -> IO (Maybe String)
binDoesntExist ...
```

My current solution without the bind-operator:

```
missingBin :: [String] -> IO [String]
missingBin xs = do
  ys <- mapM (\x -> binDoesntExist x) xs
  return $ catMaybes ys
```

I'm currently learning Haskell and try to understand how to use the different functions of the standard library. My solution works, but I guess there is a cleaner way.

Comment: And just for fun, you can actually name it `binDoesn'tExist` with the apostrophe, and it will still work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A short solution would be

```
missingBin :: [String] -> IO [String]
missingBin = fmap catMaybes . mapM binDoesntExist
```

you don't need the `>>=` operator for that.

Note: `(\x -> binDoesntExist x) = binDoesntExist`

Answer (score 5):

From the comment you've written on `binDoesntExist`, I suspect that you might rather have a different type signature, namely:

```
-- returns True if the passed binary is not present on the system
binDoesntExist :: String -> IO Bool
binDoesntExist = ...
```

The implementation of this signature will probably be simpler than your existing implementation; and *additionally* your `missingBin` will be quite a bit simpler as well:

```
missingBin :: [String] -> IO [String]
missingBin = filterM binDoesntExist
```

This discussion assumes that your existing function always returns exactly the `String` it's passed (if it returns any `String` at all); but this assumption doesn't seem so far out to me.

Comment: You are right about turning `missingBin` to `IO Bool`. The hard part after understand-how-Haskell-works is to learn how to think Haskell. Thanks for the tip.